# Android - difference between View.OnLayoutChangeListener and ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener

Tags: android, layout, view, processing

According to the doc, the first is

Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when the layout bounds of a view changes due to layout processing.

and the second is

Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when the global layout state or the visibility of views within the view tree changes.

///

But they seem pretty similar to me. I was even able to use both of them interchangeably. Can someone give me a practical example of the usage of them? Thanks

Answer (score 22):

An `OnLayoutChangeListener` is a listener for a specific `View` and will trigger only when that `View` goes through a layout pass (i.e. `onLayout()` is called).

An `OnGlobalLayoutListener` watches the entire hierarchy for layout changes (so registering one of these on any `View` in a hierarchy will cause it to be triggered when any `View` in that hierarchy is laid out or changes visibility).